# How to use mezzanine together with allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth, mezzanine

I commented mezzanine `mezzanine.accounts` from settings.INSTALLED_APPS and use allauth as `AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND`

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r"^$", include("movies.urls")),
    url("^blog2", blog_post_list, name="home"),
    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r"^movies/", include("movies.urls", namespace="movies")),
    url(r"^faq/", include("fack.urls")),
    url(r"^accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    url(r'^tz_detect/', include('tz_detect.urls')),
    url(r"^h/", include("home2.urls", namespace="home2")),
    url(r"^profile/", include("profile.urls", namespace="profile")),
    url("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
]
```

The problem is that when I go to `https://localhost/blog2`, that I see the base.html of allauth.accounts.

Maybe mezzanine confuses allauth accounts/base.html with its own accounts/base.html? Or maybe I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

`url("^blog2", blog_post_list, name="home"),`   uses blog/blog_post_list.html as template which extends base.html, but since there's no base.html inside blog/ app it used the first it could find which was in this case allauth, hence the confusion.

I.e. creating a base.html in `<project_path>/templates/base.html`, use e.g. `mezzanine/core/templates/base.html` as a template, solves it